# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'save_to_db' 0

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

I was trying to use `python` `flask` `flask-sqlalchemy` and `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` to start building a rest API, tried to save data but for some reason save method fails as this couldn"t create item object from the dictionary. Here is the codes I"ve -

https://github.com/musa-pro/flask-sqlalchemy-marshmallow

I"m kinda stuck to proceed. Could anyoneprovide me a clue?

Btw, I"ve python 3.8. I"ve added here the screenshot of packages -
[image]

Appreciate any help.
Thanks
Musa

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I had to add `load_instance = True` in Schema meta section.